# How to SELECT data from Oracle database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle

How do I fetch the `EMPNO` and `ENAME` columns from the table called `emp`?

This is my connection string:

```
if ($c = oci_connect("tharindu", "123456", "localhost/XE")) {  
   echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.";   
   oci_close($c);
} else {  
   $err = oci_error();   
   echo "Oracle Connect Error " . $err['text'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = oci_parse($c, "SELECT EMPNO,ENAME
                            FROM emp");

oci_execute($array);

while($row=oci_fetch_array($array))

{

echo $row[0]." ".$row[1];

}
```

Comment: i have error msg: Successfully connected to Oracle.
Warning: oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\temp\example2\x.php on line 11

Warning: oci_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\temp\example2\x.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: stid in C:\wamp\www\temp\example2\x.php on line 15

Warning: oci_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\temp\example2\x.php on line 15